# How to detect wordpress theme using Jquery

Tags: jquery

i have look for WP theme detector source code, but i not found, anyone can tell me how to code or share me a WP theme and plugin Detector, like http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/

Comment: Post some code to show that you tried.  We only help people who really really try and care.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: hello @xuân-hòa have you got solution of your problem..